# column data operations inside sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of increasing dates (with gaps) and corresponding values

```
date        | value
01.02.2012  | 10
02.02.2012  | 11
03.02.2012  | 33
07.02.2012  | 34
08.02.2012  | 13
```

I am looking for table of differences for values between dates, like this:

```
02.02.2012 - 01.02.2012  | 11 - 10 = +1
03.02.2012 - 02.02.2012  | 33 - 11 = +22
07.02.2012 - 03.02.2012  | 34 - 33 = +1
08.02.2012 - 07.02.2012  | 13 - 34 = -21
```

Now I am load table into excel and make calculations there, but I have feeling there is a possible way of getting it by use of sql commands inside database. Is there any?

UPD. Actually I use access as database system, but If there is a difference I can switch to one that best fit.

Comment: Which DBMS?  Some DBMS have the OLAP functionality which makes this easier to write, and others do not (which makes it fairly hard to write).

Comment: Don't store dates as strings when your DB supports date types.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: What makes you think that format is not a DATE format and is a string?

Comment: The format they are posted in. Although I suppose that could be internationalization settings.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It is a date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't think analytical functions like `Lag` are available in access you will need to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  Date,
        Value,
        NextDate,
        NextValue,
        (NextValue - Value) AS ValueDifference,
        DATEDIFF("D", Date, NextDate) AS DateDifference
FROM    (   SELECT  T.Date,
                    T.Value,
                    (   SELECT  TOP 1 Date
                        FROM    LagTest T1
                        WHERE   T1.Date >  T.Date
                        ORDER BY Date
                    ) AS NextDate,
                    (   SELECT  TOP 1 Value
                        FROM    LagTest T1
                        WHERE   T1.Date >  T.Date
                        ORDER BY Date
                    ) AS NextValue
            FROM    LagTest T
        ) AS T
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a DBMS, but this is ANSI SQL that works on most modern DBMS (it's not exactly the output you want, but it does show the difference between two values).

```
select date, 
       value,
       value - lag(value) over (order by date) as diff
from your_table
```